# Place the title of the current tab in the clipboard with a keyboard shortcut in Google Chrome

Tags: chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that allow the user to place the title of the current tab in the clipboard with a keyboard shortcut. It should work on Microsoft Windows.

There seems to be no way to do it natively: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [Shortcut manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf) chrome extension.

---

Steps:

1. Install the extention
2. Open the extention

   [image]
3. Click `Add a new Shortcut` (1)
4. Assign a shortcut (2). I used ctrl+Alt+k
5. Select Execute Javascript (3)
6. In the field shown as (4) copy the following javascript

```
function clip(text) {
    var copyElement = document.createElement('input');
    copyElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    copyElement.setAttribute('value', text);
    copyElement = document.body.appendChild(copyElement);
    copyElement.select();
    try {
        if(!document.execCommand('copy')) throw 'Not allowed.';
    } catch(e) {
        copyElement.remove();
        console.log("document.execCommand('copy'); is not supported");
        prompt('Copy the text below. (ctrl c, enter)', text);
    } finally {
        if (typeof e == 'undefined') {
            copyElement.remove();
        }
    }
}
var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
clip(title);
```

7. Click Save
8. Restart chrome

**Note:** The `document.execCommand()` used in the code is not supported on a few sites for example Wikipedia. But you should be able to circumvent it by changing the javascript or by manually pasting the above code on the console.

---

**References:**

1. Copy to clipboard script taken from [here](https://cdn.rawgit.com/Triforcey/clip-j/d4cf52adb248f236331acd8401610fc198a1fb57/clip-j.js).
2. Scrip to get the title of the current page is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229043/5157905).

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a userscript manager installed, such as Tampermonkey, you can use this userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Quick page title copier
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/
// @version      1.0
// @description  A userscript that lets you quickly copy the title of a webpage
// @author       ᔕᖺᘎᕊ (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/)
// @match        *://*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 67) {
            window.prompt('Press Ctrl+C', document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML);
        }
    }, false);
})();
```

It doesn't directly copy, like [@Aswin's](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/31753/2675) script, but it prompts you so you can just ctrl+c it.

Default shortcut is ctrl+shift+c